# Does Kafka have any configuration which limits number of messages of Kafka Consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

My problem is Kafka consumer always hangs after receiving about 10,000 messages from Kafka, when I restart Kafka Consumer it starts reading again and continues to hang at 10,000 messages. Even when I consume from all partitions of just 1 partition, Kafka Consumer does not read after 10,000 messages.

P/S: If I use KafkaSpout to read messages from Kafka, KafkaSpout stops emitting after about 30,000 messages too.

Here is my code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("group.id", "Tornado");
    props.put("zookeeper.connect", TwitterPropertiesLoader.getInstance().getZookeeperServer());
    props.put("zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms", "200000");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
    props.put("auto.commit.enable", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");

    ConsumerConfig consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig(props);
    final ConsumerConnector consumer = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(consumerConfig);

    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicCountMap.put(TwitterConstant.Kafka.TWITTER_STREAMING_TOPIC, 1);

    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(TwitterConstant.Kafka.TWITTER_STREAMING_TOPIC);

    final KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream0=streams.get(0);
    logger.info("Client ID=" + stream0.clientId());

    for (MessageAndMetadata<byte[], byte[]> message : stream0) {
        try {
            String messageReceived=new String(message.message(), "UTF-8");
            logger.info("partition = " + message.partition() + ", offset=" + message.offset() + " => " + messageReceived);
            //consumer.commitOffsets(true);
            writeMessageToDatabase(messageReceived);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Edit: this is the log file, after 10,000 messages, there is something happened like rebalancing consumer (not sure), but KafkaStream cannot continue to read message

[image]

Comment: Could it be a memory problem?

Comment: Can you clarify or edit your sentence "all partitions of just one partition"? I assume you mean "...one topic".

Comment: @Steve: As u can see, in this code above I read from partition 0 only: stream0=streams.get(0), while actually there are 3 partitions for this topic, in this case I use ExecutorService to create 3 threads, but the issue is the same